# Order now Page form at product page in opencart 3.0

Tags: product, checkout, opencart-3

I need Order Now form at product page, so that user do not need to go at checkout page step. i am using open cart 3.0.2 version.

That form must have Qty , if user add more Qty the total sum should also calculated according to the number of products. I also need to include the delivery charges in the total sum.

Comment: On default version you can't achieve this what you need. You need to order custom module. But if you are the coder, you can do it by yourself. And if something is going wrong, you can ask here by posting your attempts.

Comment: A very quick Google search shows extensions like this: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=14687

Comment: it is not compatible for version 3 or above